# Experimental Economics

Tags: reference-request, experimental-economics

I'm looking for good sources on "experimental economics" and "natural experiments" in economics.
Given the comments below to my first version of this question, and a little more reading on my part, neither of these will be covered in one book.
So perhaps you people could suggest good introductory sources for these topics.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: David Cards work **is not experimental** (I dont believe he has even a single experimental paper). The sort of work that Duflo or Banjeree (2019 Nobel Prize winners) does is experimental. 'Natural experiments' are observational studies. They are called natural experiments because these observational studies exploit some natural experiments, but the studies themselves are not really experimental, I suggest you edit your question otherwise you will get answers about *actual* experimental economics

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

When I took experimental economics as an undergrad, here are two resources assigned by the course:

1. [The Handbook of Experimental Economics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691058979/the-handbook-of-experimental-economics) - Kagel and Roth
2. [Experimental Economics: Rethinking the Rules](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691124797/experimental-economics) - Bardsley, et al.

If I'm not mistaken, they focus on lab experiments. Hopefully this helps.